# Scala method created using function literals

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and was playing around with few concepts but got stuck with following one.

If i create a method like

```
def sample(value:Int) = {(x:Int)=>x+1}
```

This works in Scala and can be tested as `sample(100)`, but I am not able to understand as how a method and literal here can be clubbed. Can someone explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: `sample` is a function which returns an anonymous function. All the concepts you're playing around, you just need to read them up a bit: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html and http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions

Comment: Thanks YoungSpice, got your point

Answer (score 5):

The parameter `value` here is never used and is therefore redundant. The method `sample()` returns a function which takes one integer parameter (which is discarded) and then adds 1 to it. So you get:

```
scala> def sample(value:Int) = { (x:Int) => x + 1 }
sample: (value: Int)Int => Int

scala> sample(100)
res2: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> sample(100)(10)
res3: Int = 11

scala> val f = sample(99)
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f(1)
res4: Int = 2
```

You could use the `value` parameter in the following way:

```
scala> def plusX(value:Int) = { (x:Int) => x + value}
plusX: (value: Int)Int => Int

scala> val plus10 = plusX(10)
plus10: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> plus10(15)
res7: Int = 25
```

Now `plusX` creates a function which takes a integer and adds the value `value` to it